# C# Razor - Uses keyword default in Html

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I got this problem : i have to use the keyword default as propriety in Razor, like this code :

```
            <tr>
                <td>default</td> 
                <td>@n.@(@default)</td>  
            </tr>
```

Where the n. is a foreach
doc.microsoft say that i have to use showed format, but doesn't work .
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-5.0

The error text is like this : "The name default does not exist in context"
but my propriety is that.

May someone help me please ?
I check out other posts but i cannot find nothing.
Regads.

> Comment added

The code is this :

```
        @foreach (///.Networks n in Model.networks)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>default</td>
                <td>@n.default</td>
            </tr>
```

networks contains the propriety defaul, the suggested "Try @(n.@default)" doesn't work, the output is :

default   ///.Networks.@default

The /// hides the real namespace

Comment: Can you show the code of `n`?

Comment: Try `@(n.@default)`

Comment: Edit my post, answer to all

Comment: There is a ton of info with different "solutions". Worth trying `@@n.default` and `@(@n.default)`

Comment: I would try:  `@(n.default)` Does that work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This worked fine : <td>@(n.@default)</td> 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `var n` to replace `///.Networks` and use `@(n.@default)` as
`madreflection` said
.Here is a demo:

property:

```
public string @default { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<table>
@foreach (var n in Model.networks)
{
    <tr>
        <td>default</td>
        <td>@(n.@default)</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, also this could be agood idea, but now seems to work.